# Button Ripple Animation Does Not Exists When Placed Inside a RecyclerView

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

So I have a `RecyclerView` Item. Inside the `RecyclerView item`, there is a `Button`.

The problem is, normally when a `button` is pressed. there are **Material ripple animations** on it.

But when a `Button` is placed inside a `RecyclerView` `Item`, the "Ripple" animation is no longer there, but **the click event of the button is still triggered**.

Anyone knows how to fix this?